# Use D output in 42099 (4X4 X-treme Off-Roader) set

Tags: electronics, control-plus

How I can use the D output for an additional motor in the [42099 set](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/4x4-x-treme-off-roader-42099)? Or how can I use a custom control skin?

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing this, it is not possible to use the Control+ hub and motors in any other configuration than the already existing preset ones. This situation is expected to change, but there are no promises regarding functionality or timeline from LEGO.